# angularjs consume asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-services

Good Day,

i am new to angularjs and started playing around mostly on the pulling of data trough web service.

my web service returns a list of latitude and longitude from my database

here is the code

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<friendlyforces> get_friendly(string regionid , string type)
        {
            List<friendlyforces> friendlies = new List<friendlyforces>();
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@regid", regionid));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", type));
            SqlDataReader readers = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connection, "friendlyforces", parameters.ToArray());
            while (readers.Read())
            {
                friendlies.Add(new friendlyforces());
                friendlies[(friendlies.Count - 1)].unit_name = readers["unit_name"].ToString();
                friendlies[(friendlies.Count - 1)].address = readers["adrress"].ToString();
                friendlies[(friendlies.Count - 1)].latitude = readers["latitude"].ToString();
                friendlies[(friendlies.Count - 1)].longitude = readers["longitude"].ToString();
                friendlies[(friendlies.Count - 1)].icon = readers["icon"].ToString();
            }

            return friendlies;
        }
```

now on my angularjs enabled page i am trying to display the data given by the web service here is the code

```
var app = angular.module('Services', []);

        app.controller('latController', function ($scope, $http) {

            var url = "Services/datapull.asmx/get_friendly";

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: JSON.stringify({ regionid: "7", type: "pnp" })
            }).success(function (data) {
                var myjson = JSON.parse(data);

                $scope.locations = JSON.parse(myjson);
            });

        })
```

now when the web service is invoked it returns an error stating that i am missing a parameter the regionid i tried `$.param : ({regionid : "7" , type : "pnp" }) and`param : JSON.stringify ({regionid : "7" , type : "pnp"})

but it retruns the same error parameter is missing

any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: What does the signature on the datapull.asmx method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the content type you provide `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, it seems you want to send your data as url param.

However,

> By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content- type, "application/json".

Try add `transformRequest` in your request.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
       var str = [];
       for(var p in obj)
       str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
       return str.join("&");
    },
    data: { regionid: "7", type: "pnp" }
    }).success(function () {});
```

Comment: thank you the web service returned as expected but the format is very new to me <ArrayOfFriendlyforces xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <friendlyforces>
    <unit_name>504th Maritime Police Station</unit_name>
    <address>Camaligan Fishing Port Complex,Bgy Dugcal, Camaligan, Cam Sur</address>
    <latitude>123.1570000</latitude>
    <longitude>13.6263864</longitude>
    <icon>/icons/PNP.png</icon>
  </friendlyforces></ArrayOfFriendlyforces> how can i parse this?

Comment: You are returning XML from your controller, which is difficult to handle in Angular. Try return JSON data.

Comment: You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize your data to JSON string.